# Register allocation rules in code generated by major C/C++ compilers

Tags: c++, c, assembly, compiler-construction, cpu-registers

I remember some rules from a time ago (pre-32bit Intel processors), when was quite frequent (at least for me) having to analyze the assembly output generated by C/C++ compilers (in my case, Borland/Turbo at that time) to find performance bottlenecks, and to safely mix assembly routines with C/C++ code. Things like using the SI register for the *this* pointer, AX being used for return values, which registers should be preserved when an assembly routine returns, etc.

Now I was wondering if there's some reference for the more popular C/C++ compilers (Visual C++, GCC, Intel...) and processors (Intel, ARM, ...), and if not, where to find the pieces to create one. Ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are asking about "application binary interface" (ABI) and calling conventions. These are typically set by operating systems and libraries, and enforced by compilers and linkers. Google for "ABI" or "calling convention." Some starting points from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) and [Debian for ARM](http://wiki.debian.org/ArmEabiPort).

Answer (score 4):

Agner Fog's "Calling Conventions" document summarizes, amongst other things, the Windows and Linux 64 and 32-bit ABIs: http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf. See Table 4 on p.10 for a summary of register usage.

One warning from personal experience: don't embed assumptions about the ABI in inline assembly. If you write a function in inline assembly that assumes return and/or parameter transfer in particular registers (e.g. eax, rdi, rsi), it will break if/when the function is inlined by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Open Watcom C/C++ compiler supports two calling conventions, register-based (default) and stack-based (very close to what other compilers use). User's Guide for this compiler describes them both and is available for free [online](http://www.openwatcom.org/ftp/manuals/1.5/cguide.pdf), together with the compiler [itself](http://openwatcom.org/index.php/Download). You may find these topics in the User's Guide especially helpful:

- 10.4.1 Passing Arguments Using Register-Based Calling Conventions
- 10.4.6 Using Stack-Based Calling Conventions
- 10.5 Calling Conventions for 80x87-based Applications

Answer (score 0):

Well, today if optimisation is turned on, there arn't any. But GCC allows you to declare that your assembly instruction should use particular variable regardless if it's in register or not, or even to force GCC tu put that variable into a register usable with your instruction. You can also declare which registers your inline assembly block reserves for itself (so compiler should generate apropriate save/restore code around your inline piece, if needed)

Answer (score 0):

I believe but am by no means sure that GCC uses the [Itanium ABI](http://www.codesourcery.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html#acknowledgements) for most of its function; the incompatibilites between it and the ABI it uses are [documented](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options).