# How does callee know arguments are passed through registers instead of stack

Tags: c++, assembly, g++, x86-64, calling-convention

Suppose we are given a simple program

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int n = argc;
    if (n > 1) {
        n = 1;
    }else {
        n = -1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

and assembly code snippet generated using `g++ main.cpp -S -O1` under ubuntu x64(Windows subsystem)

```
subq    $8, %rsp
cmpl    $1, %edi
setg    %dl
movzbl  %dl, %edx
leal    -1(%rdx,%rdx), %edx
movl    $.LC0, %esi
movl    $1, %edi
movl    $0, %eax
call    __printf_chk
movl    $0, %eax
addq    $8, %rsp
ret
```

There is neither a `push` nor any instruction that accesses and writes memory. So the argument `n` must be passed through `%edx`. Now I wonder how the c library function `__printf_chk` knows that `%edx` contains the expected argument? More generally, how does it know which register(s) has(have) used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an application binary interface (ABI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2171177/608639), [Register allocation rules in code generated by major C/C++ compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/256220/608639), [What are the different calling conventions in C/C++ and what do each mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/949862/608639), etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is specified by the platform's ABI (application binary interface).   The compiler has compiled `__printf_chk` to follow your platforms ABI (in this case, the [amd64 SysV ABI](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf)), causing it to expect arguments to be in certain locations.  For further reading, have a look at this ABI document.